# Insert array values from comma separated string into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I have this comma separated data, where rows are separated by `;`

```
04:03:49,https://foo.bar/1; 04:03:34,https://foo.bar/2; 04:03:24,https://foo.bar/3; 04:03:09,https://foo.bar/4; 04:03:07,https://foo.bar/5; 04:03:07,https://foo.bar/6; 04:02:41,https://foo.bar/7;
```

And a mysql table like this one:

| time | link |
| --- | --- |
| 04:03:49 | https://foo.bar/1 |
| 04:03:34 | https://foo.bar/2 |

So im using this code to  convert the data from $_POST to array:

```
$data=@$_POST['array'];
$array=explode(';', $data);
```

That results in:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 04:03:49,https://foo.bar/1 
  [1] => 04:03:34,https://foo.bar/2 
  [2] => 04:03:24,https://foo.bar/3 
  [3] => 04:03:09,https://foo.bar/4 
  [4] => 04:03:07,https://foo.bar/5 
  [5] => 04:03:07,https://foo.bar/6 
  [6] => 04:02:41,https://foo.bar/7 
  [7] => 
)
```

So, i need to insert that data into my db using the time in one column  and the link in the other, been trying a few  examples but can't seem to find the answer thanks in advance for the help.

I tried using this query:

```
$consulta= "DECLARE @array varchar(max) = '($array)'
SET @array = REPLACE( REPLACE(@array, ';', '), ('), ', ()', '')
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO hora (hora,link) VALUES ' + @array
EXEC (@SQLQuery)";
```

But it errors with:

```
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp8\htdocs\plantas\index.php on line 138
```

Comment: How are you inserting data in mysql . What have you tried till now ?

Comment: I've found this example but it throws an error about array to string  conversion:
`$consulta= "DECLARE @array varchar(max) = '($array)'
SET @array = REPLACE( REPLACE(@array, ';', '), ('), ', ()', '')
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO hora (hora,link) VALUES ' + @array
EXEC (@SQLQuery)";`

Comment: it would be better if you update your answer with the code you are using and the error you got

Comment: Just loop over the array to generate the VALUES sections of an INSERT statement (you can set multiple sets of values in an INSERT) and then execute that. You're aiming for this kind of structure `INSERT INTO yourtable (colA, colB) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)`

Comment: Please, if you found the solution, add it as an Answer. The solution is not part of the question. I'll give you a few minutes to sort it out and then roll back your edit. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . Glad you solved it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop over the `$array` and then explode it again using `,` separator. Then you can run MySQL insert query to insert the data in your table.

Like

```
foreach($array as $row){
  $data = explode(',', $array);
  //Run MySQL query here to insert this data in your table
  $sql_query = "INSERT INTO hora (hora,link) VALUES ('".$data[0].'", '".$data[1].'") ";
 //Something like 
  $mysqli->query($sql_query);

}
```

Remember to always **sanitize user data** befor inserting it in database

Update: if using mysqli

```
$query = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO hora (hora,link) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->bind_param("ss", $data[0], $data[1]);
$query->execute();
```

This will prevent [SQL Injection attacks](https://geekflare.com/sql-injection-prevention-php/).

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "in" in the line `foreach($row in $array){`

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection. You should show an example using parameters and prepared statements